# Laravel Job Dispatcher Hooks

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Is there a way in laravel to access or alter job/queue information(eg. connection, queue name,...) before the job is been pushed to queue.

example.

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->onConnection('alternate')->onQueue('xxx');

$this->dispatch($job);
```

Before this job get pushed into a queue i would want to dynamically access the queue name and use it to generate a configuration file to a specific location.(that is if no configuration file bears that name). And other use cases.